# How do I get my google contact's birthdays to show up in evolution calendar?

Tags: sync, evolution, calendar, google-calendar

I have synced evolution to my google calendar and google contacts. That went well.

But why can't I edit any of my contact's birthdays in evolution? And why are those birthdays not displayed in evolution's calendar? The birthdays are present in the webcalendar of google.

**Edit:** I had allready tried the method suggested by Kory Wnuk in one of the answers below. For some reason I can't click okay in that dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness:

Purging Evolution and starting all over again helped my "okay is not clickable" problem. No idea why the okay bug occurred in the first place - I had tried at least ten times on different days with no success.

Then I was able to add the birthdays calendar from google to my evolution. Adding was done using the method in the picture of my original question.

Sill a feature in evolution would be nice, that allows editing birthdays in google contacts.

Answer (score 2):

When creating the new calendar in Evolution, did you select the correct Google Calendar?

[image]

I would suggest attempting to retrieve the Google Calendar list and selecting the appropriate one with your contact's birthdays.  I am guessing that your default Google Calendar does not contain your contact;s birthdays.  You may end up having to bring in multiple calendars from Google.  At least that is what I had to do.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi and thanks. I allread tried that. See the edit of my question.